# why is my PubSub pattern not working as intended

Tags: javascript, class, model-view-controller, publish-subscribe, loose-coupling

Please I am a bit confused why my code is not working.

I am trying to practice PubSub design pattern using the code below. The class instance displayGreet is subscribed to the messaged event published by the message function. The message function is the handler for the click event attached to the button.

The goal is to get the message function to send a message to displayGreet when the button is clicked so that the greeting is updated to the browser.

I was able to achieve the desired outcome when both the displayGreet and message were written as functions. But I am unable to achieve same when displaygreet is an instance of a class.

Please help me out.

```js
class Pubsub {
    constructor() {
        this.subscribers = {};
    }

    subscribe(event, callback) {
        if (!this.subscribers[event]) {
            this.subscribers[event] = [];
        }
        this.subscribers[event].push(callback);
    }

    publisher(event, data) {
        if (!this.subscribers[event]) {
            return;
        }
        this.subscribers[event].forEach((callback) => {
            callback(data);
        });
    }
}
const pubsub = new Pubsub();
class Sub {
    constructor(pubsub) {
        this.pubsub = pubsub;
    }
    greet(greeting) {
        console.log(greeting);
        const paragraph = document.querySelector('.show')
        paragraph.textContent = greeting;
        this.pubsub.subscribe("greeted", greeting);
    }
}
const displayGreet = new Sub(pubsub);


function morning() {
    const greeting = "good morning";
    pubsub.publisher("greeted", greeting);
    return greeting;
}


const button = document.querySelector('.submit')
button.addEventListener('click', morning)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <p class="show"></p>
        <button class="submit">submit</button>
    </div>

    <script src="src/index.js">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're never subscribing to the PubSub instance. Also, `subscribe()` is expecting a callback, which must be a regular function. So you can't say `this` since that's a class instance. Use `this.greet` instead.

```js
class Sub {
    constructor(pubsub) {
        this.pubsub = pubsub;

        // Subscribe and call `this.greet`
        this.pubsub.subscribe("greeted", this.greet);
    }

    greet(greeting) {
        console.log(greeting);
        const paragraph = document.querySelector('.show')
        paragraph.textContent = greeting;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please can you clarify what you mean by "You're never subscribing to the PubSub instance?" I have effected the corrections you pointed out but still didn't get it to display the message to the browser. Thank you

Comment: You're subscribing in `greet()` but never calling `greet()`. It also looks like `greet()` is supposed to be what the PubSub is calling, so it doesn't make sense to subscribe there. You need to subscribe when you create the object.

Comment: Thank @Jessie. I moved the subscribe call to the constructor and got it to work. But I still can't really wrap my head around the workings though.